# Want to add a close button to dropdown in wpforms

Tags: html, css, dropdown, wpforms

[Required button Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MUaA.png)   Hi, I'm using wpform plugin and have designed a Multiselect dropdown form present here
https://letsshine.no/shine
I want to add a close button in Multiselect field header not to individual choices as it is already present I have attached image to make it clear. Actually I have three fields I want to make sure that when user has selected choices he can close the field or can open the next field.....
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Honestly I wouldn't. An x in a text box usually clears the text instead of closing it. The part I find weird about this is that the arrow doesn't close the box. Maybe look into that?

Comment: I want to use this "x" to close this opened dropdown. or something that can close this dropdown once the user has selected choices. I think it's possible I have seen it But I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Yeah I'd definitely focus on making the arrow do this. You should explain a bit more about the system you're using. Do you have any code available? Are there any other elements available that might do what you're looking for? I don't personally know much about wordpress, otherwise I'd be more help.

Comment: Yes, I'm using wordpress and Elementor builder may be some css or js can help us to do it. I don't have any code available. Let me explain it a bit more I want a close sign just like we have in dropdown menu to close menu...I want those similar close button but in Multiselect dropdown of wpforms. So that user can click those sign and can close the dropdown.